# How to find the height of the virtual keyboard in PhoneGap?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I need to move a textarea and button right above the virtual keyboard, like so:

[image]

For that, I need to know the height of the keyboard. I have tried using the $(window).height() method, but oddly enough, it doesn't change even when the keyboard is opened.

Any suggestions?

Comment: One question, when you open the keyboard, the view move up?

Comment: @chemitaxis I have put in a `scrollTop` function yes.

Answer (score 1):

For Iphones

**iPhone 4S (and earlier) Portrait Keyboard  (English)  320 x 216 pts**

**iPhone 4S (and earlier) Landscape Keyboard (English)  480 x 162 pts**

**iPhone 5 Portrait Keyboard  (English) 320 x 216 pts**

**iPhone 5 Landscape Keyboard (English) 568 x 162 pts**

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Comment: I don't want to hardcode any values, especially because it's a PhoneGap app that works across platforms (iOS and Android).